# What is Doctor Strange holding in this scene of Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the following snapshot from *Avengers: Infinity War*, Doctor Strange appears to be holding something, which in the next shot vanished from his hands. What is that thing? [image]

Just anything that he grabs or is it a proper prop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It is a stone.

It seems to be just a stone. Maybe Strange wanted to distract Thanos while the Avengers were getting ready to attack, or just to do something while waiting for Thanos to come for the Time Stone. There are ruins around, so finding a stone while waiting for Thanos wouldn't have been very hard. 
While talking with Thanos, he rolls the stone, and we can clearly see that it is stone.
Then, it seems he just dropped it on the ground (looks more like a filming error).

Comment: While waiting he picked up any stone just as we need to do something to pass time, happens involuntarily at times,he was noticing his surroundings,  and when Thanos arrived, he threw the stone away.

Comment: @masterArSuKa Yeah, that's right.